# Как-то можно установить порядок unit test Laravel?

Tags: laravel

К примеру, мне нужно сначала, чтобы пользователь зарегистрировался, а потом залогинился.

Сейчас оно в порядке выполняется, видимо, по списку:

```
LoginTest
RegisterTest
```

Comment: Не должно быть никаких зависимостей между тестами, соответственно, порядок не важен

Comment: К примеру мне нужно еще создать токен passport а как пользователь авторизуется если его еще нет в базе? или это делатиь все в одном методе логин то есть добавления токена, регистрация и тут же авторизация?

Comment: В каждом тесте надо мокать объекты, создавать токены и т.п. Напр. создать пользователя чтобы потом что-то сделать достаточно просто - `$user = User::factory()->create();`, User - модель, factory() - использует, напр. [UserFactory](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-factories#introduction)

Comment: Каждый тест должен быть независим. В тесте логина - создаешь юзера, добавляешь в базу, проверяешь аутентификацию. В тесте регистрации - создаешь юзера, пытаешься его зарегать нужными методами. Это две разные операции

Comment: @lezhni _создаешь юзера, добавляешь в базу_ - это не одно и то же?

Comment: @InDevX зависит от ситуации. При создании нового экземпляра модели данные еще не лежат в базе, иногда есть смысл напрямую создать модель, а не добавить её в базу и потом достать

Comment: @InDevX например, есть сервис, который на вход принимает юзера. Проще просто создать модель и проверить сервис, передав её туда, чем проводить дополнительные манипуляции с базой

Comment: @lezhni не об этом речь, фраза "создаешь юзера" путает, просто создать экземпляр App\Models\User  это не создание юзера, с базы брать предпочтительней потому что попутно проверяются все параметры, аля ошибки если забываешь убрать timespamps и пр., а при создании объекта этого не будет и получается тесты говорят всё Ок а на деле работать не будет

Comment: Смотря какой тест. Если я проверяю сервис - я проверяю сервис и передаваемый туда параметр. Проверка валидности значения в базе - это уже другой тест и другая ответственность

Comment: @lezhni а если делать универсально то есть в роуте есть маршрут а этот маршрут уже в контроллер и там сервисы и все тоесть проверить сразу все передать данные в api

Comment: @ProgRamm это уже не будет unit-тестом, это итеграционный/сквозной тест. Но они тоже довольно важны, так как позволяют протестировать какой-то цельный кусок взаимодействия частей приложения (роутер, контроллер, модель, база, прочее)

Comment: @lezhni то есть это будет feature test там такие размещать?

Comment: @ProgRamm да, верно. Unit-тесты обычно тестируют какой-то один определенный класс (или класс с зависимостями). Рекомендую полистать книгу "Принципы юнит-тестирования" Владимира Хорикова, она очень хорошо рассказывает большинство нюансов